Snowflake roles and accountadmin privileges on a DB
-- current user (accountadmin): rsahu 
use role useradmin;
create role r1;

use role useradmin;
create role r2;

use role useradmin;
grant role r1 to user rsahu;
grant role r2 to user rsahu;

use role sysadmin;
grant create database on account to role r1;

use role r1;
create database db1;
show grants on database db1; -- ownership by r1

use role r2;
drop database db1; -- success, how?

rsahu has different roles granted to it: accountadmin, useradmin, sysadmin, securityadmin, r1 and r2.
Using role r2, how did the last statement succeeded even though r2 does not have any privilege on db1?
TIA!

Are you using Secondary Roles? Try running SELECT CURRENT_SECONDARY_ROLES(); using the r2 role and see if it returns r1?

Secondary roles may be used. Before you switch to role r2, use the command below and try the drop.
use secondary roles none;

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/use-secondary-roles
